# how to Monitor tcp stats in windows with java program

Tags: java, tcp, monitoring

I want to monitor how many TCP connections that my system has through JAVA program.
In Linux, there is file that contains all the info about TCP connections.
Name of the file is  /proc/net/tcp 
From that file I can monitor but is there any file like that in windows so that I can monitor TCP data from that file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the netstat command. You can execute this command from java by using RunTime class

```
        { 
            Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c netstat"); 
            p.waitFor(); 
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
            ); 
            String line=reader.readLine(); 
            while(line!=null) 
            { 
                System.out.println(line); 
                line=reader.readLine(); 
            } 

        }
```

Comment: one problem with above program, is that  i need send and receive queue size of TCP connections,while net-stat command doesn't show those fields

Comment: execute "netstat -a" it will give u the size of sending and receiving q too.

Comment: in windows "netstat -a" wont give the sending and receiving queue

Answer (score 0):

It seems [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/) is just what you need. You did not specify what precise information you need, but there are lots of ready-to-use statistics provided by the JVM, including file descriptor usage. You might want to explore it with JConsole first - [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) is an introduction to JConsole from Oracle.

Edit: while there does not seem to be any standard way to obtain precisely TCP connections count, there is a linux-specific way to get total number of open file descriptors: `OperatingSystem.OpenFileDescriptorCount` property.

Comment: how can i monitor tcp connections through jmx, i don't think there is way with jmx we can monitor only applications, servers etc ..not tcp connections